# Why time.clock() returns such a large value on Windows Server 2008 X64

Tags: python, time

I ran following script on different machine and got quite different results. The elapsed time.clock() is so large.

Script:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
import time
start_clock = time.clock()
time.sleep(60)
end_clock = time.clock()
print "Sleep Clock = ", str(end_clock - start_clock)

start_time = time.time()
time.sleep(60)
end_time = time.time()
print "Sleep Time = ", str(end_time - start_time)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Output:

```
Instance (Windows Server 2008, X64):
Sleep Clock =  938.306471633
Sleep Time =  60.0119998455

Local Machine (Windows Vista, X86):
Sleep Clock =  59.9997987873
Sleep Time =  59.996999979
```

Following result really confused me:
*Sleep Clock =  938.306471633*

P.s:
I have not tested on other X64 OSs. This Windows Server 2008 is a running Amazon Instance.

Comment: FYI, I ran the code on a Win7 x64 machine and got values close to 60 for both time() and clock() methods.

Comment: Are you consistently getting these values?  Any chance that the clock was updated during your test, perhaps a network time service that kicked in?

Comment: Thanks Philip.
It seems the result is not very stable. I remember it can be about 700, not always close to 900 instead.
I am not sure if it's because I ran this script on an Amazon Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 2):

Per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html?highlight=time.clock#time.clock) on `time.clock`

> On Windows, this function returns
>   wall-clock seconds elapsed since the
>   first call to this function, as a floating point number, based on the Win32 function QueryPerformanceCounter().

so my (blind, i.e., I've never seen Amazon's code for Windows virtualization!-) guess would be that Amazon's virtualization doesn't go quite deep enough to trick `QueryPerformanceCounter` (which is a very low-level, low-overhead function).  Tricking `time.time` (in a virtualizing hypervisor) is easier (and a more common need).

Do you know what happens e.g. on Microsoft's Azure, and with other non-Microsoft virtualizers such as Parallels or VMWare?  I wouldn't be surprised to see different "depth" to the amount of "trickery" (deep virtualization) performed in each case.  (I don't doubt that the explanation for this observation must have to do with virtualization, although the specific guess I make above could be flawed).

It would also be interesting to try (again, on various different virtualizers) a tiny C program doing just `QueryPerformanceCounter`, just to confirm that Python's runtime has nothing to do with the case (I believe so, by inspection of the runtime's source, but a confirmation could not hurt -- unfortunately I don't have access to the resources needed to try it myself).