# Is there an alternative precise timer to time.clock() on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, time, python-2.7, virtual-machine

Running in Windows on some Virtual Machine platforms, Python's time.clock() function is inaccurate.
I did some testing on a few different platforms with the following test script:

```
import datetime
import time
import timeit

startClock = time.clock()
startTime = time.time()

while (True):
    currentClock = time.clock()
    currentTime = time.time()

    clockDiff = currentClock - startClock
    timeDiff = currentTime - startTime

    print (datetime.datetime.now())
    print ('time.clock() Seconds: %s' % str(clockDiff))
    print ('time.time() Seconds:  %s' % str(timeDiff))
    print ('Diff:              %s' % str(clockDiff - timeDiff))
    print ''

    time.sleep(5)
```

Depending on which Virtual Machine platform I was running on, the difference between clockDiff and timeDiff varied greatly. I tried Parallels Desktop 8 for Mac, VMWare Fusion 5, and Hyper-V.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2395677/why-time-clock-returns-such-a-large-value-on-windows-server-2008-x64). The issue is with how the hypervisors handle the low-level [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

I want accuracy in my timing, regardless of what hypervisor this might be running on. I could just use time.time(), though that doesn't have the precision that I get from time.clock().

Is there an alternative timer to time.clock() that gives me the same precision? I'm running Python 2.7 on Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`timeit` provides [`default_timer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer) which supposedly returns the most accurate portable timing mechanism on the current system.

Comment: On Windows, `timeit.default_timer()` uses `time.clock()`. Based on what I can tell `timeit.default_timer()` is for getting the most _precise_ timer, not particularly the most accurate one.